# ValueError: signal only works in main thread in signal.signal() when using with Flask python

Tags: python, flask, exception, python-requests, signals

I'm kind of new to such concepts in python and I was working with a big python file/project.
However, while running the code smoothly there was no error in this part of the code.
I was directly calling the function

```
generate_external_dataset(header, url):
```

which was extracting all the features of URL safe and smooth.

```
key = '4gggs40g888go4oko0kg0o80ccgko8c4co84kkgg'

import signal


class TimedOutExc(Exception):
    pass


def deadline(timeout, *args):
    def decorate(f):
        def handler(signum, frame):
            raise TimedOutExc()

        def new_f(*args):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
            signal.alarm(timeout)
            return f(*args)
            signal.alarm(0)

        new_f.__name__ = f.__name__
        return new_f

    return decorate


@deadline(40)
def is_URL_accessible(url):
    print('is url accessible')
    page = None
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    except:
        parsed = urlparse(url)
        url = parsed.scheme + '://' + parsed.netloc
        if not parsed.netloc.startswith('www'):
            url = parsed.scheme + '://www.' + parsed.netloc
            try:
                page = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
            except:
                page = None
                print('none')
                pass

    if page and page.status_code == 200 and page.content not in ["b''", "b' '"]:
        print('feature_extractor: line 92')
        return True, url, page
    else:
        return False, None, None


def get_domain(url):
    o = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    return o.hostname, tldextract.extract(url).domain, o.path


def getPageContent(url):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    url = parsed.scheme + '://' + parsed.netloc
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
    except:
        if not parsed.netloc.startswith('www'):
            url = parsed.scheme + '://www.' + parsed.netloc
            page = requests.get(url)
    if page.status_code != 200:
        return None, None
    else:
        return url, page.content

#              Data Extraction Process

def extract_data_from_URL(hostname, content, domain, Href, Link, Anchor, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon, IFrame, Title,
                          Text):
    Null_format = ["", "#", "#nothing", "#doesnotexist", "#null", "#void", "#whatever",
                   "#content", "javascript::void(0)", "javascript::void(0);", "javascript::;", "javascript"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser', from_encoding='iso-8859-1')

    # collect all external and internal hrefs from url
    for href in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', href['href'])]
        if hostname in href['href'] or domain in href['href'] or len(dots) == 1 or not href['href'].startswith('http'):
            if "#" in href['href'] or "javascript" in href['href'].lower() or "mailto" in href['href'].lower():
                Anchor['unsafe'].append(href['href'])
            if not href['href'].startswith('http'):
                if not href['href'].startswith('/'):
                    Href['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + href['href'])
                elif href['href'] in Null_format:
                    Href['null'].append(href['href'])
                else:
                    Href['internals'].append(hostname + href['href'])
        else:
            Href['externals'].append(href['href'])
            Anchor['safe'].append(href['href'])

    # collect all media src tags
    for img in soup.find_all('img', src=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', img['src'])]
        if hostname in img['src'] or domain in img['src'] or len(dots) == 1 or not img['src'].startswith('http'):
            if not img['src'].startswith('http'):
                if not img['src'].startswith('/'):
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + img['src'])
                elif img['src'] in Null_format:
                    Media['null'].append(img['src'])
                else:
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + img['src'])
        else:
            Media['externals'].append(img['src'])

    for audio in soup.find_all('audio', src=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', audio['src'])]
        if hostname in audio['src'] or domain in audio['src'] or len(dots) == 1 or not audio['src'].startswith('http'):
            if not audio['src'].startswith('http'):
                if not audio['src'].startswith('/'):
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + audio['src'])
                elif audio['src'] in Null_format:
                    Media['null'].append(audio['src'])
                else:
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + audio['src'])
        else:
            Media['externals'].append(audio['src'])

    for embed in soup.find_all('embed', src=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', embed['src'])]
        if hostname in embed['src'] or domain in embed['src'] or len(dots) == 1 or not embed['src'].startswith('http'):
            if not embed['src'].startswith('http'):
                if not embed['src'].startswith('/'):
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + embed['src'])
                elif embed['src'] in Null_format:
                    Media['null'].append(embed['src'])
                else:
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + embed['src'])
        else:
            Media['externals'].append(embed['src'])

    for i_frame in soup.find_all('iframe', src=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', i_frame['src'])]
        if hostname in i_frame['src'] or domain in i_frame['src'] or len(dots) == 1 or not i_frame['src'].startswith(
                'http'):
            if not i_frame['src'].startswith('http'):
                if not i_frame['src'].startswith('/'):
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + i_frame['src'])
                elif i_frame['src'] in Null_format:
                    Media['null'].append(i_frame['src'])
                else:
                    Media['internals'].append(hostname + i_frame['src'])
        else:
            Media['externals'].append(i_frame['src'])

    # collect all link tags
    for link in soup.findAll('link', href=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', link['href'])]
        if hostname in link['href'] or domain in link['href'] or len(dots) == 1 or not link['href'].startswith('http'):
            if not link['href'].startswith('http'):
                if not link['href'].startswith('/'):
                    Link['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + link['href'])
                elif link['href'] in Null_format:
                    Link['null'].append(link['href'])
                else:
                    Link['internals'].append(hostname + link['href'])
        else:
            Link['externals'].append(link['href'])

    for script in soup.find_all('script', src=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', script['src'])]
        if hostname in script['src'] or domain in script['src'] or len(dots) == 1 or not script['src'].startswith(
                'http'):
            if not script['src'].startswith('http'):
                if not script['src'].startswith('/'):
                    Link['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + script['src'])
                elif script['src'] in Null_format:
                    Link['null'].append(script['src'])
                else:
                    Link['internals'].append(hostname + script['src'])
        else:
            Link['externals'].append(link['href'])

    # collect all css
    for link in soup.find_all('link', rel='stylesheet'):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', link['href'])]
        if hostname in link['href'] or domain in link['href'] or len(dots) == 1 or not link['href'].startswith('http'):
            if not link['href'].startswith('http'):
                if not link['href'].startswith('/'):
                    CSS['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + link['href'])
                elif link['href'] in Null_format:
                    CSS['null'].append(link['href'])
                else:
                    CSS['internals'].append(hostname + link['href'])
        else:
            CSS['externals'].append(link['href'])

    for style in soup.find_all('style', type='text/css'):
        try:
            start = str(style[0]).index('@import url(')
            end = str(style[0]).index(')')
            css = str(style[0])[start + 12:end]
            dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', css)]
            if hostname in css or domain in css or len(dots) == 1 or not css.startswith('http'):
                if not css.startswith('http'):
                    if not css.startswith('/'):
                        CSS['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + css)
                    elif css in Null_format:
                        CSS['null'].append(css)
                    else:
                        CSS['internals'].append(hostname + css)
            else:
                CSS['externals'].append(css)
        except:
            continue

    # collect all form actions
    for form in soup.findAll('form', action=True):
        dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', form['action'])]
        if hostname in form['action'] or domain in form['action'] or len(dots) == 1 or not form['action'].startswith(
                'http'):
            if not form['action'].startswith('http'):
                if not form['action'].startswith('/'):
                    Form['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + form['action'])
                elif form['action'] in Null_format or form['action'] == 'about:blank':
                    Form['null'].append(form['action'])
                else:
                    Form['internals'].append(hostname + form['action'])
        else:
            Form['externals'].append(form['action'])

    # collect all link tags
    for head in soup.find_all('head'):
        for head.link in soup.find_all('link', href=True):
            dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', head.link['href'])]
            if hostname in head.link['href'] or len(dots) == 1 or domain in head.link['href'] or not head.link[
                'href'].startswith('http'):
                if not head.link['href'].startswith('http'):
                    if not head.link['href'].startswith('/'):
                        Favicon['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + head.link['href'])
                    elif head.link['href'] in Null_format:
                        Favicon['null'].append(head.link['href'])
                    else:
                        Favicon['internals'].append(hostname + head.link['href'])
            else:
                Favicon['externals'].append(head.link['href'])

        for head.link in soup.findAll('link', {'href': True, 'rel': True}):
            isicon = False
            if isinstance(head.link['rel'], list):
                for e_rel in head.link['rel']:
                    if (e_rel.endswith('icon')):
                        isicon = True
            else:
                if (head.link['rel'].endswith('icon')):
                    isicon = True

            if isicon:
                dots = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', head.link['href'])]
                if hostname in head.link['href'] or len(dots) == 1 or domain in head.link['href'] or not head.link[
                    'href'].startswith('http'):
                    if not head.link['href'].startswith('http'):
                        if not head.link['href'].startswith('/'):
                            Favicon['internals'].append(hostname + '/' + head.link['href'])
                        elif head.link['href'] in Null_format:
                            Favicon['null'].append(head.link['href'])
                        else:
                            Favicon['internals'].append(hostname + head.link['href'])
                else:
                    Favicon['externals'].append(head.link['href'])

    # collect i_frame
    for i_frame in soup.find_all('iframe', width=True, height=True, frameborder=True):
        if i_frame['width'] == "0" and i_frame['height'] == "0" and i_frame['frameborder'] == "0":
            IFrame['invisible'].append(i_frame)
        else:
            IFrame['visible'].append(i_frame)
    for i_frame in soup.find_all('iframe', width=True, height=True, border=True):
        if i_frame['width'] == "0" and i_frame['height'] == "0" and i_frame['border'] == "0":
            IFrame['invisible'].append(i_frame)
        else:
            IFrame['visible'].append(i_frame)
    for i_frame in soup.find_all('iframe', width=True, height=True, style=True):
        if i_frame['width'] == "0" and i_frame['height'] == "0" and i_frame['style'] == "border:none;":
            IFrame['invisible'].append(i_frame)
        else:
            IFrame['visible'].append(i_frame)

    # get page title
    try:
        Title = soup.title.string
    except:
        pass

    # get content text
    Text = soup.get_text()

    return Href, Link, Anchor, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon, IFrame, Title, Text

#              Calculate features from extracted data


def extract_features(url):
    def words_raw_extraction(domain, subdomain, path):
        w_domain = re.split("\-|\.|\/|\?|\=|\@|\&|\%|\:|\_", domain.lower())
        w_subdomain = re.split("\-|\.|\/|\?|\=|\@|\&|\%|\:|\_", subdomain.lower())
        w_path = re.split("\-|\.|\/|\?|\=|\@|\&|\%|\:|\_", path.lower())
        raw_words = w_domain + w_path + w_subdomain
        w_host = w_domain + w_subdomain
        raw_words = list(filter(None, raw_words))
        return raw_words, list(filter(None, w_host)), list(filter(None, w_path))

    Href = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    Link = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    Anchor = {'safe': [], 'unsafe': [], 'null': []}
    Media = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    Form = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    CSS = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    Favicon = {'internals': [], 'externals': [], 'null': []}
    IFrame = {'visible': [], 'invisible': [], 'null': []}
    Title = ''
    Text = ''

    state, iurl, page = is_URL_accessible(url)
    print('URL = ', url)
    if state:
        content = page.content
        hostname, domain, path = get_domain(url)
        extracted_domain = tldextract.extract(url)
        domain = extracted_domain.domain + '.' + extracted_domain.suffix
        subdomain = extracted_domain.subdomain
        tmp = url[url.find(extracted_domain.suffix):len(url)]
        pth = tmp.partition("/")
        path = pth[1] + pth[2]
        words_raw, words_raw_host, words_raw_path = words_raw_extraction(extracted_domain.domain, subdomain, pth[2])
        tld = extracted_domain.suffix
        parsed = urlparse(url)
        scheme = parsed.scheme

        Href, Link, Anchor, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon, IFrame, Title, Text = extract_data_from_URL(hostname, content,
                                                                                                   domain, Href, Link,
                                                                                                   Anchor, Media, Form,
                                                                                                   CSS, Favicon, IFrame,
                                                                                                   Title, Text)
        #print(Href, Link, Anchor, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon, IFrame, Title, Text)
        print('before feature row')
        row = [
               # url-based features
               urlfe.url_length(url),
               urlfe.url_length(hostname),
               urlfe.having_ip_address(url),
               urlfe.count_dots(url),
               urlfe.count_hyphens(url),
               urlfe.count_at(url),
               urlfe.count_exclamation(url),
               urlfe.count_and(url),
               urlfe.count_or(url),
               urlfe.count_equal(url),
               urlfe.count_underscore(url),
               urlfe.count_tilde(url),
               urlfe.count_percentage(url),
               urlfe.count_slash(url),
               urlfe.count_star(url),
               urlfe.count_colon(url),
               urlfe.count_comma(url),
               urlfe.count_semicolumn(url),
               urlfe.count_dollar(url),
               urlfe.count_space(url),

               urlfe.check_www(words_raw),
               urlfe.check_com(words_raw),
               urlfe.count_double_slash(url),
               urlfe.count_http_token(path),
               urlfe.https_token(scheme),

               urlfe.ratio_digits(url),
               urlfe.ratio_digits(hostname),
               urlfe.punycode(url),
               urlfe.port(url),
               urlfe.tld_in_path(tld, path),
               urlfe.tld_in_subdomain(tld, subdomain),
               urlfe.abnormal_subdomain(url),
               urlfe.count_subdomain(url),
               urlfe.prefix_suffix(url),
               urlfe.random_domain(domain),
               urlfe.shortening_service(url),

               urlfe.path_extension(path),
               urlfe.count_redirection(page),
               urlfe.count_external_redirection(page, domain),
               urlfe.length_word_raw(words_raw),
               urlfe.char_repeat(words_raw),
               urlfe.shortest_word_length(words_raw),
               urlfe.shortest_word_length(words_raw_host),
               urlfe.shortest_word_length(words_raw_path),
               urlfe.longest_word_length(words_raw),
               urlfe.longest_word_length(words_raw_host),
               urlfe.longest_word_length(words_raw_path),
               urlfe.average_word_length(words_raw),
               urlfe.average_word_length(words_raw_host),
               urlfe.average_word_length(words_raw_path),

               urlfe.phish_hints(url),
               urlfe.domain_in_brand(extracted_domain.domain),
               urlfe.brand_in_path(extracted_domain.domain, subdomain),
               urlfe.brand_in_path(extracted_domain.domain, path),
               urlfe.suspecious_tld(tld),
               urlfe.statistical_report(url, domain),

               # # # content-based features
               ctnfe.nb_hyperlinks(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.internal_hyperlinks(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.external_hyperlinks(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.null_hyperlinks(hostname, Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.external_css(CSS),
               ctnfe.internal_redirection(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.external_redirection(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.internal_errors(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.external_errors(Href, Link, Media, Form, CSS, Favicon),
               ctnfe.login_form(Form),
               ctnfe.external_favicon(Favicon),
               ctnfe.links_in_tags(Link),
               ctnfe.submitting_to_email(Form),
               ctnfe.internal_media(Media),
               ctnfe.external_media(Media),
               #  # additional content-based features
               ctnfe.sfh(hostname, Form),
               ctnfe.iframe(IFrame),
               ctnfe.popup_window(Text),
               ctnfe.safe_anchor(Anchor),
               ctnfe.onmouseover(Text),
               ctnfe.right_clic(Text),
               ctnfe.empty_title(Title),
               ctnfe.domain_in_title(extracted_domain.domain, Title),
               ctnfe.domain_with_copyright(extracted_domain.domain, Text),

               # # # thirs-party-based features
               trdfe.whois_registered_domain(domain),
               # trdfe.domain_registration_length(domain),
               # trdfe.domain_age(domain),
               trdfe.web_traffic(url),
               trdfe.dns_record(domain),
               trdfe.google_index(url),
               trdfe.page_rank(key, domain),
               ]
        print('row:', row)
        return row
    print("returning None")
    return None


#             Intialization

ctn_headers = [
    'nb_hyperlinks',
    'ratio_intHyperlinks',
    'ratio_extHyperlinks',
    'ratio_nullHyperlinks',
    'nb_extCSS',
    'ratio_intRedirection',
    'ratio_extRedirection',
    'ratio_intErrors',
    'ratio_extErrors',
    'login_form',
    'external_favicon',
    'links_in_tags',
    'submit_email',
    'ratio_intMedia',
    'ratio_extMedia',
    'sfh',
    'iframe',
    'popup_window',
    'safe_anchor',
    'onmouseover',
    'right_clic',
    'empty_title',
    'domain_in_title',
    'domain_with_copyright',

]

ctn_hyperlinks_headers = [
    'nb_hyperlinks',
    'ratio_intHyperlinks',
    'ratio_extHyperlinks',
    'ratio_nullHyperlinks',
    'nb_extCSS',
    'ratio_intRedirection',
    'ratio_extRedirection',
    'ratio_intErrors',
    'ratio_extErrors',
    'external_favicon',
    'links_in_tags',
    'ratio_intMedia',
    'ratio_extMedia'
]

ctn_abnormalness_headers = [
    'login_form',
    'submit_email',
    'sfh',
    'iframe',
    'popup_window',
    'safe_anchor',
    'onmouseover',
    'right_clic',
    'empty_title',
    'domain_in_title',
    'domain_with_copyright'

]

url_headers = ['length_url',
               'length_hostname',
               'ip',
               'nb_dots',
               'nb_hyphens',
               'nb_at',
               'nb_qm',
               'nb_and',
               'nb_or',
               'nb_eq',
               'nb_underscore',
               'nb_tilde',
               'nb_percent',
               'nb_slash',
               'nb_star',
               'nb_colon',
               'nb_comma',
               'nb_semicolumn',
               'nb_dollar',
               'nb_space',
               'nb_www',
               'nb_com',
               'nb_dslash',
               'http_in_path',
               'https_token',
               'ratio_digits_url',
               'ratio_digits_host',
               'punycode',
               'port',
               'tld_in_path',
               'tld_in_subdomain',
               'abnormal_subdomain',
               'nb_subdomains',
               'prefix_suffix',
               'random_domain',
               'shortening_service',
               'path_extension',

               'nb_redirection',
               'nb_external_redirection',
               'length_words_raw',
               'char_repeat',
               'shortest_words_raw',
               'shortest_word_host',
               'shortest_word_path',
               'longest_words_raw',
               'longest_word_host',
               'longest_word_path',
               'avg_words_raw',
               'avg_word_host',
               'avg_word_path',
               'phish_hints',
               'domain_in_brand',
               'brand_in_subdomain',
               'brand_in_path',
               'suspecious_tld',
               'statistical_report'

               ]

url_struct_headers = [
    'ip',
    'https_token',
    'punycode',
    'port',
    'tld_in_path',
    'tld_in_subdomain',
    'abnormal_subdomain',
    'prefix_suffix',
    'random_domain',
    'shortening_service',
    'path_extension',

    'domain_in_brand',
    'brand_in_subdomain',
    'brand_in_path',
    'suspecious_tld',
    'statistical_report'
]


tpt_headers = [
    # 'phish_hints',
    'whois_registered_domain',
    'web_traffic',
    'dns_record',
    'google_index',
    'page_rank'

]

headers = url_headers + ctn_headers + tpt_headers

#              Generate datasets

def generate_external_dataset(header, url):
  
    try:
        print('url before: ', url)
        res = extract_features(url)
        print('url after: ', url)
    except:
        res = None
        print('fe: 911')
        pass

    if res != None:
        with open('test_instance.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerow(res)
            print('writing.. closed')
            csvfile.close()
        state = 'Ok'
       
    else:
        state = 'Er'

import time
```

However, when I used flask python to extract the URL from the HTML and then call that function, it doesn't go as expected and caught an exception.

```
# Initialize the flask App
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('RfChisqFYPmodel.pkl', 'rb'))


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # For rendering results on HTML GUI

    url = request.form['url']
    print('url: ', url)
    generate_external_dataset(headers, url)
    df = pd.read_csv('test_instance.csv')
    pval_list = ['length_url', 'web_traffic', 'safe_anchor', 'ratio_extMedia', 'ratio_intMedia', 'links_in_tags',
                 'nb_hyperlinks', 'phish_hints', 'avg_word_path', 'longest_word_path', 'longest_words_raw',
                 'google_index', 'length_words_raw', 'page_rank', 'length_hostname', 'nb_eq', 'shortest_word_host',
                 'nb_and', 'nb_www', 'ip', 'nb_qm', 'nb_extCSS', 'avg_word_host', 'avg_words_raw', 'nb_semicolumn',
                 'nb_slash', 'tld_in_subdomain', 'nb_hyphens', 'longest_word_host', 'statistical_report',
                 'prefix_suffix', 'empty_title', 'nb_dots', 'nb_com', 'domain_in_title', 'nb_at', 'shortest_word_path',
                 'ratio_digits_url', 'nb_percent', 'ratio_digits_host', 'domain_with_copyright', 'abnormal_subdomain',
                 'dns_record', 'ratio_intHyperlinks', 'external_favicon', 'suspecious_tld', 'shortening_service',
                 'ratio_extRedirection', 'domain_in_brand', 'http_in_path', 'nb_dslash', 'nb_underscore', 'tld_in_path',
                 'https_token', 'brand_in_subdomain', 'whois_registered_domain', 'brand_in_path', 'popup_window',
                 'nb_external_redirection', 'shortest_words_raw', 'nb_subdomains', 'ratio_extHyperlinks', 'nb_dollar',
                 'nb_star', 'nb_redirection', 'nb_tilde', 'nb_colon', 'login_form', 'ratio_extErrors', 'punycode']
    df = df[pval_list]
    prediction = model.predict(df)
    if prediction == 0:
        output = 'phishing'
    else:
        output = 'legitimate'


    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=(output))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There is a value error generated

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/haroonrb64/Downloads/Web Filtering App/feature_extractor.py", line 1112, in predict
    generate_external_dataset(headers, url)
  File "/home/haroonrb64/Downloads/Web Filtering App/feature_extractor.py", line 894, in generate_external_dataset
    res = extract_features(url)
  File "/home/haroonrb64/Downloads/Web Filtering App/feature_extractor.py", line 375, in extract_features
    state, iurl, page = is_URL_accessible(url)
  File "/home/haroonrb64/Downloads/Web Filtering App/feature_extractor.py", line 45, in new_f
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

**Can anyone please help me come up with a solution to this error. I have spent so much time on this and I have to submit this project in a day or two!**

Comment: What exception? Where does `is_URL_accessible` get called? What did you pickle to use as the model?

Comment: @chepner the function `is_URL_accessible` gets called in the function of `extract_features`
  
I have also added the full code. You can check it out now.

 `Text = '' 
state, iurl, page = is_URL_accessible(url)
print('URL = ', url)
if state:`

Comment: @chepner I pickle and Random Forest model in a separate `.py` file. That file is working perfectly since I ran it manually by not using Flask.